# How to prove that $\| Ax \| \le \|A\| \|x\| $ for $x \in X$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear space and suppose $A : X \mapsto Y$ be bounded linear operator i.e. there exits $c>0, \| Ax \| \le c \|x\| .$
The how to prove that $\| Ax \| \le \|A\| \|x\| $ for all $x \in X$.
Here $$ \|A\| = \inf{ \{ c \ge 0 : \| Ax \| \le c \|x\| ~~\forall x~ \in X \}} .$$
One side is obvious, because $ \|A\| \le c$. Now how to prove that there exist some $x \in X$ such that $c > \|A\|.$

Comment: Exercise: $\inf\{c\geq 0:\lVert Ax\rVert\leq c\lVert x\rVert\}=\sup\{\lVert Ax\rVert/\lVert x\rVert:x\neq 0\}$.

Comment: Yes, I proved that both the numbers are equal. But, is my approach right?

Comment: Suppose it's >. Is that true or a contradiction?

Comment: @mavavilj But if there exist $x \ne 0$ such that $\|Ax\| =c\|x\| $, then can we say that $c = \|A\|$.

Comment: @Mathnerd You're complicating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\mathcal C=\inf{\{c\ge0\mid\Vert Ax\Vert\le c\Vert x\Vert,\ \forall x\in X\}}$ is nonempty since $A$ is bounded. Therefore there exists a sequence $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\mathcal C^{\mathbb N}$ which converges to $\Vert A\Vert$. Let $x\in X$. By definition, we have for all $n\in\mathbb N$
$$
\Vert Ax\Vert\le c_n\Vert x\Vert,
$$
hence for $n\to+\infty$,
$$
\Vert Ax\Vert\le \Vert A\Vert\Vert x\Vert.
$$

Comment: Got it, $\mathcal{C}$ should be inf of the set.